# Review audit data to find where data was missing and for how long

Tags: sql

I need to review audit records where an ExternalRefId string field is null which shouldn't be, then determine how long it takes till the next record with matching a UserId (not PK) int has that field populated if at all.

I'd know how to do it using entityframework/linq2sql but I can't get my head around how to produce such a result in SQL.

Ideally just to determine if more than an hour has passed but it might change to 30m.

Presently the table looks like,

```
UserId | ExternalRefId   |    Action | Timestamp

xxxx  |  (xxxx-xxxx)/(null) | Insert/update/delete | xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx
```

With an ideal output of,

```
UserId  |  NullLengthOfTime

(xxxx)    |  (xxxx-xx-xx...) / (null)
```

Right now I'm working at multiple selects with excepts between to filter down but I figure this kind of query will really require cursors which I've not used before.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated.

Edit:-

ExternalRefId (ERI)

The ERI should always be populated but as it causes isses when it's null as these are whole table audits so the only time it isn't required is on deletes which will no longer be displayed. (It's external records we're sent that we audit and often the EFI isn't sent which then breaks the main record)

Comment: Is it possible to have several `update` records for the same user which leave the `ExternalRefId` as null, or can we assume that because it's been updated something's changed so it must no longer be null?

Comment: Similarly, if the record is deleted (rather, a `delete` entry is logged in the audit table) and the `ExternalRefId` is null, is that a resolution; i.e. because the offending data was deleted; or is that still an issue (because the value in the audit table is still null)?

Comment: @JohnLBevan There can be many update records which "Should" all keep the ExternalRefId (ERI) but sometimes the data isn't sent as as such is left null, it can happen on inserts/updates or deletes but it's not an issue for deletes. The ERI should always be populated but causes issues when it's missing for inserts/updates.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Cool.. . please take a look at the code I've provided and let me know if that meets your requirements...  I'll add explanatory text once I know the answer I've given meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

#### Setup Demo Data

```
declare @MyAuditTable table 
(
    UserId nvarchar(32) not null 
    ,ExternalRefId nvarchar(32) null
    ,Action nvarchar(32) not null
    ,Timestamp DateTime not null
)

insert @MyAuditTable (UserId, ExternalRefId, Action, Timestamp)
values ('Anne', '123','insert','2017-01-01 00:00:00')
, ('Anne', null,'update','2017-01-05 00:00:00')
, ('Anne', null,'update','2017-01-06 00:00:00') --it's already null, so don't show this again
, ('Bill', null,'insert','2017-01-07 00:00:00')
, ('Anne', '1234','update','2017-01-09 00:00:00')
, ('Claire', null,'insert','2017-02-02 00:00:00')
, ('Bill', '456','update','2017-02-24 00:00:00')
, ('Claire', null,'delete','2017-04-13 00:00:00') --though it's still null it's deleted, so fixed by removal
, ('Dave', null,'insert','2017-09-28 00:00:00') --never fixed, so doesn't show up
, ('Anne', null,'update','2017-10-14 00:00:00') --someone broke Anne again!
, ('Anne', '123','update','2017-10-15 00:00:00') --fixed
```

#### Actual Query

```
select EntryMadeInvalid.UserId
, EntryMadeInvalid.TimeStamp IssueBegan
, EntryMadeValid.TimeStamp  IssueEnded --will show null if issue is still open 
, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EntryMadeInvalid.TimeStamp, coalesce(EntryMadeValid.TimeStamp,getutcdate())) NullLengthOfTimeInMinutes --if issue is still open reports up to current time
from
(
    --find all entries which create or amend a value to become null
    Select *
    from @MyAuditTable a
    where ExternalRefId is null 
    and Action in ('Insert', 'Update')
    and --ignore scenarios where the null issue already existed
    (
        select top 1 case when b.ExternalRefId is null then 1 else null end
        from @MyAuditTable b
        where b.UserId = a.UserId
        and b.Timestamp < a.Timestamp
        order by b.Timestamp desc
    ) is null
) EntryMadeInvalid 
outer apply
(
    select top 1 *
    from @MyAuditTable
    where UserId = EntryMadeInvalid.UserId
    and Timestamp > EntryMadeInvalid.TimeStamp
    and (Action = 'Delete' or ExternalRefId is not null)
    order by Timestamp 
) EntryMadeValid
```

#### Results

```
UserId | IssueBegan              | IssueEnded              | NullLengthOfTimeInMinutes
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Anne   | 2017-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2017-01-09 00:00:00.000 | 5760
Bill   | 2017-01-07 00:00:00.000 | 2017-02-24 00:00:00.000 | 69120
Claire | 2017-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-13 00:00:00.000 | 100800
Dave   | 2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 | NULL                    | 239884
Anne   | 2017-10-14 00:00:00.000 | 2017-10-15 00:00:00.000 | 1440
```

#### Explanation

**Subquery `EntryMadeInvalid`**

The purpose of this code is to find those entries where the data first becomes incorrect.  Incorrect is defined as the `ExternalRefId` being null.

I also filter on `Action in ('Insert', 'Update')` since to become null presumably the data has to have been inserted or updated; that's optional though.

Finally I remove any entries which didn't make the value null but rather left it at null.  This is done by finding the immediate predecessor for the same user and seeing if the ExternalRefId is null.  If it is then we don't care about this record.  If it's not, or no previous record exists for this user, then this is the first time the value's become null since having a value (or not existing).

**Subquery `EntryMadeValid`**

The purpose of this query is to find where the given record changes back from being null to having a value.

We do this by selecting the first record after then null record which is for the same user for which the ExternalRefId is not null (or where the action is delete; if we make the assumption that once a record's been deleted it's null value is no longer an issue).

**Outer Apply**

Essentially we're doing a join; only instead of returning the full table and then trying to match up the records, we're taking each result from the first set and using it to filter data for the second set before returning it.

We're using `outer` instead of `cross` since we still want the first record even where there is not result from the second subquery; i.e. we want those values which are still null / have never been corrected.

Comment: It's partially there but doesn't account for repeat issues with the same user and ideally it could include those that are presently borken although I believe I could work that out by simply comparing presently broken users with their last audit record in order to to a date diff of now till the audit's timestamp.

Comment: I also changed the NullLengthOfTime to, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, EntryMadeInvalid.TimeStamp, EntryMadeValid.TimeStamp) NullLengthOfTime

Comment: No worries, amended to handle the repeat issue scenario (both where a null entry is made after an existing null, and where a previously fixed issue is made null again)... Working on next bit now...

Comment: another way to understand the issue would be to compare it to a user chat audit, the users can come and go or move between rooms to chat. The EFI could be compared to a session ID would would stay the same when they switch rooms and only change if they disconnect and return. The issue being the EFI isn't always being sent when it should never be null, I'm trying to figure out who has lost that data for more than an hour before being updated and then produce a count of occurrances.

Comment: Good example; makes sense.  Is the updated version what you're after?

Comment: Thanks that seems to be it exactly, I'm just testing some of the data and I had to add in extra timestamp restrictions to cut down of the sheer number of records.

Comment: No worries. I've added some notes to help explain what's going on... hopefully it all makes sense but please ping back if you've any questions.